# How to create a custom form with codebehind to List in Sharepoint2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I Created a list definition & list instance for Sharepoint2010 in Visual Studio (C#). Also created Application page, that by default stores in layouts folder. My goal is to make that page as new form of my list.
As I understood, It should be done in that part of list schema:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

I Tryed:

1) Add `<New>_layouts/PIUVS/ProjectsNew.aspx</New>` in `<forms>` tag. => then nothing happends

2) Change SetupPath to "_layouts/PIUVS/ProjectsNew.aspx" => while deploying appears error: *Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)*

P.S. I don't use SP Designer or programs like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

This should be done not exactly in schema file.

To add custom form to list in Sharepoint2010 you should modify a content type. In `<ContentType>` tag add following:

```
<XmlDocuments>
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
    <FormsUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
      <New>_layouts/PIUVS/ProjectsNew.aspx</New>
    </FormsUrls>
  </XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

Also copy this in ContentType reference in list's schema.